# How to write SQL query in linq

Tags: sql, linq

Could anyone please let me know how I can write the following `SQL` query in `linq`:

```
SELECT approvaldate, issubmitted, companyemail, * 
FROM registrations r 
WHERE (r.issubmitted = 'true')
  AND (r.approvaldate IS NULL) 
  AND (companyemail LIKE '%gmail%' 
       OR companyid IN (SELECT companyid FROM companies 
                        WHERE companyname LIKE '%gmail%')
      )
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet. 
(Let me know if any concern because i have not tested query)

```
var query = (from r in registrations
             Where r.issubmitted  = true 
                   && r.approvaldate.HasValue == false
                   && ( 
                        r.companyemail.IndexOf("gmail") >= 0
                       ||
                         companies.Any(c => c.companyid  == r.companyid  && c.companyname.IndexOf("gmail") >= 0)
                       )     
             select r).ToList();
```

Please check below link for reference

http://csharp-guide.blogspot.in/2012/05/linq-to-sql-sub-queries.html

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = registrations.Where(x=>
                x.issubmitted &&
                x.approvaldate == null &&
                (
                    companyemail.Contains("gmail") ||
                    companies.Any(y => y.companyid  == x.companyid &&
                                       y.companyname.Contains("gmail"))
                ));
```